# SQL Schema with self reference in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I need this create statement (MySQL) in laravel 4 schema code. Can someone please help?
The parent_id should be allowed to be empty (null).

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cms_page_410d0aac` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `parent_id_refs_id_ca1f299f` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `cms_page` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You need also to specify constraint name? because Laravel do it automatically. the `id` can be negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Schema::create('pages', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');;
        $table->unsignedInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('cms_page');
    });
```